# How to insert horizontal line between list items

Tags: itemize

I need to insert a line between two particular items in a list. The way I do it (below) creates too much vertical space around the line, and the line is not in the middle between bottom of previous item and top of next item. How can I fix it?

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item text
    \item text\\
          \rule[0cm]{8cm}{0.4pt}
    \item text
    \item text
\end{itemize}
```

I'd like the horizontal line to be evenly spaced between bottom of previous item and top of next item. The vertical distance between items separated by line can be increased a bit to accommodate the line.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item text
    \item text
      \vspace{0.1cm}
      \hrule
      \vspace{-0.1cm}
    \item text
    \item text
\end{itemize}
```

This way you can manually adjust the space